# ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript fails inside events (buttons, GridView etc.)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a simple javascript which alerts a text.

```
function AlertTest() {
    alert('test');
}
```

I'm trying to call this from code-behind, by doing the following:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "AlertTest", "AlertTest();", true);
```

This works fine. However when I try calling it within events like button_click or GridView1_RowCommand, it doesn't get called. Any suggestion on how to resolve this?

Thanks.

Edit:

I also tried calling it the following way:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(GridView1, GridView1.GetType(), "AlertTest", "AlertTest();", true);
```

Comment: show your .aspx for button click or how you called from button click??

Answer (score 0):

Check this in your files
1. Script tag must not be after  you are calling

if you are using update panels, 
Change

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "AlertTest", "AlertTest();", true);
```

To

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1,UpdatePanel1.GetType(), "AlertTest", "AlertTest()", true);
```

You can also provide full function Server side

```
    var script = "alert('hELLO');";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1, UpdatePanel1.GetType(), "AlertTest", script, true);
```

here you can Save Message in other class